# not getting desired borders

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Ive created buttons with xml, but am assiging their width and height programmatically. In the xml Ive also assigned that the buttons go like style X which defines that the buttons should have a fill and a border. The button's fill comes out as desired but the border is only on the bottom of each botton(creating one long horizontal line bc all bottons are right next to each other). Ive been trying to figure out whats wrong for a while but cant seem to come up with anything, can someone please help?

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/row6"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/row5"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/taf"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_taf"
            style="@style/CalculatorButtons" />
```

this is an example of one button inside my LinearLayout

```
<style name="CalculatorButtons">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/calculator_buttons_background</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

and here is the style

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<solid
    android:color="#ff2b407d"
    />
<stroke
    android:color="#ff868686"
    android:width="1px"
    />
```

and here is drawable

What i want is that each button has a gray border around it

Comment: Post your xml. Also add a link to an image of what is going wrong and a detailed description of exactly what you want.

Comment: that is so weird i was taking an emulator screen shot of what is happening to post but when I saw the picture everything looked fine!! If it isn't showing right on the emulator is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
  <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
  <stroke android:width="0.7dip" android:color="#D3D3D3"/>
</shape>
```